# Deserialize JSON object containing JArray to C# object

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on a Server-Client application. The Client has a thread that his main goal is receiving from the server the "room's state".

My problem is Deserializing the JSON packet to a C# object.

```
public class roomState //This is the class that I want to create
    {
        public int isActive { get; set; }
        public int questionCount { get; set; }
        public int answerTimeOut { get; set; }
        public JArray players { get; set; }
    }

string jsonObject = "{\"isActive\":<int>,\"questionCount\":<int>,\"answerTimeOut\":<int>,\"players\": [\"name1\",\"name2\",\"name3\"....]}"
```

the string above is an example of what I'm receiving from the server.
How do I deserialize this?

*I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq but not bound only to this.

Thank you in advance, Anthon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Newtonsoft.Json` for this purpose:

```
public RoomState DeserializingMyRoomState()
{   
    string jsonObject = "{\"isActive\":<int>,\"questionCount\":<int>,\"answerTimeOut\":<int>,\"players\": [\"name1\",\"name2\",\"name3\"....]}";        
    RoomState myRoomState = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoomState>(jsonObject);
    return myRoomState;
}
```

And please, when naming a class in C# I would suggest you to use Pascal Case, so your class should be named `RoomState`.

UPDATE:
Also, consider structuring all your classes that would be used for JSON serialization/deserialization in the following way:

```
public class RoomState
{
      [JsonProperty("isActive")]
      public int IsActive { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("questionCount")]
      public int QuestionCount { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("answerTimeOut")]
      public int AnswerTimeOut { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("players")]
      public List<string> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I will add that you must use List<string> instead of JArray if you want to modify the list, or string[] if you don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did try it but now I know why it didn't work!

Comment: Error The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context. What do I need to include? (using Newtonsoft....)

Comment: Just add: using Newtonsoft.Json;
Of course, make sure that you have this package installed in your solution/project.

Comment: You need nuget Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Yeah, I just used the whole namespacing path and it worked. But now it can't deserialize players:{"Error converting value \"[\"an123\"]\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 'players', line 1, position 59."} Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Comment: @AnthonNaivelt Please, check out my updated answer. Try to always use this pattern for your classes in C#.

Comment: That is also inside Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Thanks, I found it.

Comment: It still cant deserialize players

Comment: +  $exception {"Error converting value \"[\"an123\"]\" to type 'System.String[]'. Path 'players', line 1, position 59."} Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Comment: Can you copy json you are trying to parse, I will check it locally?

Comment: response "{\"answerTimeout\":5,\"isActive\":false,\"players\":\"[\\\"an123\\\"]\",\"questionCount\":5}" string

Comment: why there are 3 slashes before and after the name?

Comment: I fix the order of the class

Comment: public class roomState
        {
            [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("answerTimeout")]
            public int answerTimeout { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("isActive")]
            public bool isActive { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("players")]
            public string[] players { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("questionCount")]
            public int questionCount { get; set; }
        }

Comment: Just copy the class after the fix and the string

Comment: I don't know how and where do you get this JSON from, but it is definitely not structured the right way. Currently you are expecting List or Array of string[] and it should be just List or Array of strings. Try hardcoding your JSON like this: string jsonObject = "{\"answerTimeout\":5,\"isActive\":false,\"players\": [\"an123\"],\"questionCount\":5}" and then deserialize it, it should work.

Comment: I don't have the server's code, I'm working on the client. So what should I do?

Comment: I called the server's programmer and he fixed the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome! There was a way to handle it also on client's side, but that was definitely not the best way. You're good to go now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Fluent-JSON.NET](https://github.com/masbicudo/Fluent-Json.NET) if you do not want to pollute your models with attributes.

```
public class RoomStateMap: JsonMap < RoomState > {
  public RoomStateMap() {
    this.Map(x => x.isActive, "isActive");
    this.Map(x => x.questionCount, "questionCount");
    this.Map(x => x.answerTimeOut, "answerTimeOut");
    this.Map(x => x.players, "players");
  }
}
```